# How can I avoid asking users to login (connect) to my facebook app again and again?

Tags: facebook

I am developing and testing a facebook app for which I have granted the permissions with my facebook account. Then the app is authorized to access my info, etc. nicely. The next time I close the browser, reopen it, login to facebook successfully then access the app, facebook wants me to login to that app again. I can access the current user id, but how can I automatically authorize the app (if the user has already authorized in the past) without needing the user to press that dread 'Login' button again and again upon each session's end?

Comment: Are you using the Javascript API or something else?

Comment: I'm using the default php-sdk given as in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** - offline_access has been deprecated. Read this post for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

You will need to request a token that has offline_access so that you can use their authentication token over and over again. Then you will need to set a cookie yourself that stores something indicating who the user is. Facebook does not support a "remember me" feature in their authentication so you have to build it yourself. Store the access token in your database and set the cookie to identify the user.

Unless you are building this for a very specific reason like an app that runs on work computers only, I would really encourage you to not implement this feature. The facebook connect authorization is well understood by users and is very easy to use. You are going to get a lot more security if you make your users press the button every time. Just make sure you make this optional. You never know if somebody is on a public computer.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I'm trying to implement what most fb apps do: you only have to allow it once to post on your wall, etc., then you never have to sign in again or press any connect links.