# show Facebook album without asking user to login to Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook OG SDK by creating a FB app to display a particular public Facebook page's album (first picture).

Have put the JS code together and it works well but I can see (for the purpose that we have in mind) - it's going to be really inconvenient to ask the user to login to FB every time to have it work (i.e. fetch the access token and pull the image down).

Here is the code so far:

```
<script>
    // initialize and setup facebook js sdk
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '123456789xxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
            document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.'
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook.';
        }
    });

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // login with facebook with extra permissions
    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
                document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.'
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook.';
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'});
    }

    // show the first image in a gallery
    function getPhotie() {
    FB.api(
      '/10152939029743105',
      'GET',
      {"fields":"photos.limit(1){link,images}"},
      function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
        document.getElementById('status-photie').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.photos.data[0].images[0].source + "'>";
      });
    }
</script>
```

And here is the HTML in the test page:

```
<div id="status-photie" style="border: solid 1px orange;"></div>
<button onclick="getPhotie()">Get photie</button>

<div id="status"></div>
<button onclick="login()" id="login">Login</button>
```

Right now, you need to click on the login button for it to fetch the token and connect to the app (the ID of which I have obfuscated above). Then if you click on the "Get Photie" button, the image loads into the div.

What we want to do (end goal) is to create a "tile" where the first image of the facebook page's album automatically loads into - without requiring a user to login to Facebook first for it to happen.

Is this at all remotely possible??

I did find this other thread which seemed to suggest that it isn't: [How can I avoid asking users to login (connect) to my facebook app again and again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149027/how-can-i-avoid-asking-users-to-login-connect-to-my-facebook-app-again-and-aga)

Comment: You can use your app or a page access token instead. But those must never be exposed in client-side code, which means you need to make the API calls server-side instead.

Comment: CBroe, could you point me towards a server-side solution by way of a link? Hopefully it's a PHP code solution...

Comment: Tis' ok. Think I have found it - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens

Comment: I've looked into using an app token via server side scripting but it appears that it still requires user authentication. I can't find any evidence of a method where it does not ask a user to login to their facebook account. Does such a method exist?

Comment: No, it doesn’t require user authentication. You get the app token once, and store it somewhere in your code/database. No further user interaction required.

Comment: Yep, I managed to figure that part out. I even got the 'infinite' page token to work. My big issue is that the token is exposed. I don't have access to the db to store it safely. Only other way I can think of is using PHP SDK. Is it possible to leave token exposed and give the app read only permission - and still mitigate risk?

Comment: It doesn’t have to be stored inside a database - as long as you use it only server-side (in your PHP script), it is not exposed.

Comment: I have to do this on a CMS with no access to backend or PHP unfortunately. Does this kind of operation need to use a token? The page is public and anyone can view album. This was much easier to do in Instagram.

Comment: I have to do this on a CMS with no access to backend or PHP unfortunately. Does this kind of operation need to use a token? The page is public and anyone can view album. This was much easier to do in Instagram.

Comment: Yes, it needs a token.

Comment: Cool, it's all sorted now. Managed to do it server side through GET request to retrieve JSON feed. Just had to get the correct syntax sorted from OG.